# Mongoose - access populated object's virtual attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, model

I understand that I can create virtual attributes on a model (ex - an author has a virtual that allows it to access all their associated documents in a publications model).

I have the following models (note the virtual `name` attribute in the author model)

```
// book.js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var debug = require('debug')('local-library:server');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BookSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author', required: true },
  // summary: { type: String, minlength: 150, maxlength: 500, required: true },
  summary: { type: String, required: true },
  isbn: { type: String, required: true, validate: {
    validator: (toValidate) => {
      // some kind of REGEX can go here
      return true;
    }
  }},
  genre: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Genre' },
})

BookSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(function() {  // can not use arrow functions here b/c they lack binding
  return `/catalog/books/${this._id}`
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)
```

```
// author.js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100 },
  family_name: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100 },
  date_of_birth: { type: Date },
  date_of_death: { type: Date }
});

// Virtual attribute for author's full name
// I think this is not dissimilar to making an instance method
// on a Rails model class like def fullName; return self.first_name + self.last_name; end
AuthorSchema
.virtual('name')
.get(() => {
  let fullName = '';

  if (this.first_name && this.family_name) {
    fullName = `${this.family_name}, ${this.first_name}`
  }

  return fullName;
});

// Virtual attribute for author's lifespan (year range of author's life)
AuthorSchema
.virtual('lifespan')
.get(() => {
  return `${this.date_of_birth.getYear().toString()} - ${this.date_of_death ? (this.date_of_death.getYear().toString()) : 'present'}`
})

// Virtual attribute for author's url 
// (so you don't have to have this type of parsing logic all over the place whenever you need to access data about this author)
AuthorSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(function() {
  return `/catalog/authors/${this._id}`
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema)
// export default mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema)
```

In my books controller, I have the following:

```
// show
exports.books_show = (req, res, next) => {
  Book
    .findById(req.params.bookId, 'title author')
    .populate('author')
    .exec((err, book) => {
      if (err) { 
        return next(err) 
      } else {
        res.render('./catalog/books/books_show.pug', { title: "Book Show", book: book, id: req.params.bookId })
      }
    })
}
```

I am having a hard time accessing the populated object's (i.e., the author's) virtual attribute of `name`

[Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) describe something like adding a virtual `books` attribute to the `author` model, so that you can `populate()` an author with their books, which doesn't really seep appropriate here since I'm going in the other direction / want to access a virtual property of the populated model that doesn't really have anything to do with books, I just want to access the functionality of the author's virtual attribute.

Is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue stemmed from using arrow functions when I defined the virtual attributes for the populated model's schema, which caused the virtual attribute's logic to not function as expected.